# Deleting a file with LFTP using variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp, lftp

I'm trying to delete a file from an FTP server in my shell scrip using LFTP, but for some reason it will not use my variables, and takes them as literals.

The code:

```
USERNAME="theuser"
PASSWORD="verygoodpassword"
SERVER="example.com"
BACKUPDIR="thebackups"
FILETODELETE="uselessfile.obsolete"

lftp -e 'rm /${BACKUPDIR}/${FILETODELETE}; bye' -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $SERVER
```

What I want it to do is run:

```
lftp -e 'rm /thebackups/uselessfile.obsolete; bye' -u theuser,verygoodpassword example.com
```

But instead it runs:

```
lftp -e 'rm /${BACKUPDIR}/${FILETODELETE}; bye' -u theuser,verygoodpassword example.com
```

And of cause it can not find the literal file "/${BACKUPDIR}/${FILETODELETE}" on the FTP server and complains thus.

What am I doing wrong???

Cheers!

Comment: +1 for question, a. well formatted, b. clear explanation of goal, c. clear explanation of work O.P. had done so far. Good luck and keep posting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because you are using simple quote instead of double quotes.

Change this and will work

```
USERNAME="theuser"
PASSWORD="verygoodpassword"
SERVER="example.com"
BACKUPDIR="thebackups"
FILETODELETE="uselessfile.obsolete"

lftp -e "rm /${BACKUPDIR}/${FILETODELETE}; bye" -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $SERVER
```